# Instant Drupal documentation

Tags: 7

I am on Drupal 7. I would like to ask if you know of any Drupal modules or tools that will 'spit' (sorry for using this term) an instant documentation of a given Drupal install (Drupal version, installed modules list, installed modules versions and maybe some more information). Thank you!

Comment: Someone downvoted me. May I know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about one module to do it all, but [Enabled Modules](https://drupal.org/project/enabled_modules) will show you the list of modules and their versions.

To view a sites status, and Drupal version, you can log in and visit admin/reports/status

Comment: Thank you, Chris, your answer is more what I was expecting. Although I had done some search, I could not find this module.

Answer (score 1):

[Drush](https://drupal.org/project/drush) is your best tool for this..

> Drush is a command line shell and Unix scripting interface for Drupal.

For Example

```
drush status
```

Provides a birds-eye view of the current Drupal installation.

Drupal version                  :  7.22
 Site URI                        :
 Database driver                 :  mysql
 Database username               :  root
 Database name                   :  d7
 Database                        :  Connected
 Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful
 Drupal user                     :  Anonymous
 Default theme                   :  bartik
 Administration theme            :  seven
 PHP configuration               :
 Drush version                   :  6.0-beta1
 Drush configuration             :
 Drush alias files               :  /Users/Anilsagara/.drush/pantheon.aliases.d 
                                    rushrc.php
 Drupal root                     :  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/d7
 Site path                       :  sites/default
 File directory path             :  sites/default/files
 Private file directory path     :  sites/default/files/private
 Temporary file directory path   :  /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php

Comment: Anil, thank you for sending this information. For sure it will help me and I can use this in conjunction with the module 'Enabled Modules' suggested by Chris below. I currently don`t have Drush installed in the server running this Drupal install I am running, but this is definitely a good solution.